# What is risk if I use aspnet_membership

Tags: asp.net-membership, asp.net-2.0

I have some doubt about aspnet_membership. My database team of my company dosen't let me use aspnet_membership. Because this feature use some stored procedure to install some thing that break the policy of my company. They said this feature could make some risk but I don't know what risk that I'll get if I used it.

Does anyone have any idea or reason about this issue?

Answer (score 7):

Your "database team" is obviously paranoid. What sort of security risk do they anticipate if the `aspnet_regsql.exe` tool creates a database? I can understand that many Administrators feel uneasy using wizards because they want to know exactly what is going on behind the scenes. In this case, the command line tool allows you a high degree of customizability and should be preferred over the wizard mode.

Perhaps you and your database team should read up on the [published implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862(VS.80).aspx) of the tool, rather than being obstinate about which you are ignorant. If you still find "[Creating the Application Services Database for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x28wfk74.aspx)" to be overkill, it is quite possible to create your own MembershipProviders and PersonalizationProviders and incorporate them with your own database structure.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but (as most good questions do) it made me think.

I can see the perspective of your database team in certain scenarios:

1. You are subject to compliance regulations that require complete separation of duties and thorough step-by-step documentation of every change made to an environment. This means that you can't just run any utility (no matter how well-documented or tested) on your own; you must hand it off to another team for approval, and that team must understand (in theory) every potential impact.
2. Perhaps there is a very granular object by object security policy in place, and your database team feels that auto-generated table structures would violate this.
3. Not a security breach, but depending on naming standards you have in place, the tables/procedures created by the tool may violate those conventions.
4. Perhaps you work in finance or healthcare and there is a specific set of security requirements that must be met. Either through ignorance or research, your database team believes that the membership database will not meet these requirements.

I've worked with many companies that have draconian security policies that often cause a great deal of extra time to be spent. Conversely, the consequences of not following those policies can have such dire consequences (multi-million dollar fines here in the US) that caution/paranoia usually wins out.

In summary: if the ASP.Net authentication/authorization scheme is a good fit, then invest the time in educating the database team on its internals so they can be comfortable with it. Listen to their objections; DBAs can be over-protective of their environments, but they often are responsible for key assets of a company.

As @Cerebrus pointed out, there are many different ways to use ASP.Net security. Try to leverage the parts that make sense. If your database team still doesn't "get it" (or raises valid objections) there are plenty of other ways to implement robust security in ASP.Net, they just require more effort.